# Get the object behind a React element

Tags: reactjs

How can I get the JS object that describes a React element? For example:

```
const Test = ()=> {
  return (
     <div> Hello world</div>
  )
}
```

When calling the above component by `<Test />` what am I getting, under the hood, is an object describing what `<Test />` returns. This should be like:

```
{
  $$typeof:
  key: null,
  type: 'div',
  ...
}
```

***How can I see the exact structure/content of the above React element?***

Comment: `console.log(<div> Hello world</div>)`?

Comment: Is there a way to use the component itself? `console.log(< Test />)` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned *does* contain the exact structure and content of the React element. JSX is syntaxic sugar for `React.createElement`, which returns an object describing how to render the component with the intent of providing that information to `ReactDOM` for rendering on the page.

You can access that object and manage rendering yourself, if you're so inclined to write your own implementation of a React renderer.

See here:

[image]

Comment: My question is if it is possible to get the above information by using the component that returns the React element...

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper You just call `Test()` (in your case) and you will get this information from it. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Actually, what is the difference between `<Test />` and `Test( )`?

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper `<Test />` is syntaxic sugar for `React.createElement(Test, {}, null)` https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects

Comment: @ Slava Knyazev, last question for you: 

`return (
    <>
    {console.log(<Test />)}
    <Test />
    </>
  );`
Why we do not take the corresponding React element in the console?

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper I don't understand the question. This returns an empty fragment and logs the return of `React.createElement(Test)`

Comment: `<Test />` inside console.log does not return `<div>Hello  world</div>`.  I am getting an object whose `props:{}` and `type: () => {…}` instead of `props: {children: 'Hello world'}` and `type: 'div'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252514/discussion-between-slava-knyazev-and-unknown-developer).